# How to detect user defined local styles

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way eith javascript to detect if the user uses own local styles in the browser?
E.g. if he/she is using the Stylish-plugin and/or the browsers settings to add custom styles?

Comment: open your site chrome and used to Inspect element plugin, Ie Open your site and press F12  , Link from chrome https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview

Comment: How would detecting user-defined styles “help people using styles for more contrast”?

Comment: I can think of one good use case. Accessibility - some users use a locally defined stylesheet to enhance accessibility - think high contrast or other perceptual disabilities. However these stylesheets may overwrite other things, such as using icon sprites or different kinds of overlays. Using a script to detect if the person is using a local stylesheet can save a lot of headaches for all concerned.

Comment: Use JavaScript to detect the applied style for a select suite of test elements? Not a guarantee just a heuristic.